# Can I create a TriggerIO File instance from Base64 data to pass to forge.request.ajax?

Tags: android, ajax, trigger.io, forge

Good day, SO.

Using Trigger.IO's javascript SDK, is it possible to create a Forge [`File`](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/file.html#modules-file) object from Base64 data suitable for passing to Forge's `forge.request.ajax` method?

I am attempting to upload an image to a server that requires submission in the form of an oldschool `multipart/form-data` request (can't be changed, unfortunately) from my TriggerIO mobile app. The image comes from `canvas.toDataURL()` in Base64 format.

Android 2.2 lacks both `FormData`, `BlobBuilder` and typed arrays -- making this exercise difficult via `XMLHttpRequest` (though I have it working well on all other modern platforms). I'm wondering if I might be able to get some joy using Trigger IO's Forge's [`forge.request.ajax`](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/request.html)?

Comment: Hi Paul, not currently possible no: the File object has to come from the native side originally. We'd be open to adding a "canvas to PNG" sort of API if that would fit the bill? Creating a File from a base64 seems like a less useful subset...

Comment: Hi James. Thanks for the answer, stick it below so that I can accept it for prosperity. 

I wouldn't consider the creation of file instances from raw data to be particularly esoteric. The use of `toDataURL()` is becoming fairly popular. One of the nice things about it is that the data can be made easily displayed inside an application via `src=""` data URI. Forge's `File` object effectively implements much of the newer [`File API`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/), which I think is a big plus for TriggerIO. I'd suggest continuing along those lines and supporting procedural File creation

Comment: Although a super-fast, native "canvas to PNG" function would certainly be welcome too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @James Brady's comment, this cannot be done as of the current version (v1.4).

> " The File object has to come from the native side originally "